# Перенести вычисления на видеокарту

Tags: c#, многопоточность, gpu

Есть программа, в которой проводится цикл и в нем параллельные вычисления. Все вычисления, как я понял, проходят на процессоре, использую всё его ядра. С помощью чего именно я могу переправить все вычисления с процессора на видеокарту, чтобы быстрее всё рассчитывалось?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вот сейчас как раз начал читать про Cuda. Буду писать свою программу под это. Спасибо)

Comment: @nick_n_a мне не майнить надо, да и я это тоже делал. А тут всё же уже в самом программировании, как реализовать. Но уже в принципе понял, нужно изучать документации

Comment: @nick_n_a [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [OpenCL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)( Open Computing Language — открытый язык вычислений).